# what are the guidelines for the key in the max function & is that key related to the dictionary keys in Python ? ex: max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])

Tags: python, key

I am a beginner in Python , I tried to understand how this (2nd line) works.
Is it comparing the lowercase letters based on the key (which is the repetition of the letter in the text string) ?

```
    text = text.lower()
    return max(string.ascii_lowercase, key=text.count)
```

From documentation , I found max(arg1, arg2, *args[, key])
but there is no definition for what is the key in the function

What are the guidelines for the key in the max function & is that key related to the dictionary keys in Python ?

Thanks for illustration

Comment: Look over the documentation for the built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=max#max) function

Comment: There is almost certainly a description of the named `key` parameter.

Comment: did you read the docs?  The [key function for sorting](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions) provides a similar function.

Comment: "The key argument specifies a one-argument ordering function like that used for list.sort()".

Comment: in docs , only `key=keyfunc` is written , so I didn't understand this.
I have already checked docs for the max function , but the key part is still ambiguous for me , is it the same as the python keys of the dictionary ?

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy The documentation contains the quote I posted above. https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#max

Comment: sorry , I didn't see it initially , I thought that keywords would be highlighted and at the sentence beginning (which is not the case here)

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For every character in `string.ascii_lowercase`, this calls `text.count()`, and picks the character for which `text.count()` has returned the highest count.

In other words, this finds the lowercase ASCII letter that occurs in `text` most frequently.

Comment: Thanks for illustrating , for the **key** is it the same as the python keys of the dictionary ? what are the guidelines for that key ?

Comment: @AhmedElkoussy: It's a callable that gets applied to every element. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max

Comment: Thank you , I got lost by the other definitions (iterable, ...) & mixed up with the dictionary keys

Answer (score 1):

The key is the criteria in which the `max()` function will consider a maximum (the criteria used when comparing elements), so when `key=text.count`, you're having the following conversation with `max()` :

- you : Get the maximum letter.
- `max()` : what do you consider a maximum letter.
- you : the maximum letter is the letter that has the most count.

Comment: Thanks for illustration